# Object Array in JAVA giving InputMismatchException

Tags: java, arrays, object, inputmismatchexception

Code and Snap of the Exception are attached. Pls Help me out with InputMismatchException. I believe there is something wrong while entering the value at runtime

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ObjectArray
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner key=new Scanner(System.in);
        Two[] obj=new Two[3];

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            obj[i] = new Two();
            obj[i].name=key.nextLine();
            obj[i].grade=key.nextLine();
            obj[i].roll=key.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(obj[i].name);
        }
    }
}

class Two
{
    int roll;
    String name,grade;
}
```

[image: Exception]

Comment: please provide the exception logs.

Comment: You are probably not entering the data in the correct order. It looks like you need to enter a String, String, then an int, 3 times. It helps to add println() statements before each `nextLine()` or `nextInt()` call so you know what type of data to enter next.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*'Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()'*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint). You need to call `nextLine` after the call to `nextInt`. Otherwise the program gets one `nextXXX` call ahead of you. At the point you input `R`, the programming is asking for `nextInt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
obj[i].roll=key.nextInt();
```

Use:

```
obj[i].roll=Integer.parseInt(key.nextLine());
```

This ensures the newline after the integer is properly picked up and processed.

Answer (score 1):

use `Integer.parseInt(key.nextLine());`

```
public class ObjectArray{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    Two[] obj = new Two[3];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        obj[i] = new Two();
        obj[i].name = key.nextLine();
        obj[i].grade = key.nextLine();
        obj[i].roll = Integer.parseInt(key.nextLine());
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name = " + obj[i].name + " Grade = " + obj[i].grade + " Roll = " + obj[i].roll);
    }
}
```

}

```
class Two {
    int roll;
    String name, grade;
}
```

**output**

```
a
a
1
b
b
2
c
c
3
Name = a Grade = a Roll = 1
Name = b Grade = b Roll = 2
Name = c Grade = c Roll = 3
```